# Proving an integration with a modified Bessel function and an exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, improper-integrals

I am trying to prove the following identity:

[image]

where $\mu, h, H$, and $\tilde{\gamma}$ are real constants.
The only hint that I have is use the relation between the modified bessel function of the first kind and the bessel function of the first kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your equation, as shown below :

[image]